# Was Bane part of the League of Shadows during the time Bruce was being trained?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises, batman-begins

Both Bruce Wayne and Bane were obviously trained by the League of Shadows so it seems quite possible that their time with the League of Shadows could've coincided.

Bane was in the pit for a long time but had he been rescued from the pit and joined the League of Shadows when Bruce was there?

Answer (score 13):

When Talia left the pit she is seen to be quite young maybe between 10-15, so assuming that she went and found here father who then returned and freed Bane (who doesn't look significantly older) within 5 years then I imagine that Bane would have been excommunicated from the League of Shadows well before Bruce Wayne was there.

That is based on the assumption that Talia and Bruce are roughly the same age.

Also Talia says that she could not forgive her father for excommunicating Bane from the League of Shadows until Bruce killed him suggesting that she was angry at him for a long time, however Bruce only killed Ra's Al Ghul a short while after he trained with the league so it would seem that Talia and Bane were not there.

When Bruce is training with the league in Batman Begins he talks to Ra's Al Ghul about his parents death and Ra's Al Ghul tells him that he had a wife but that she was taken from him, I imagine he would mention his daughter at this point if she was there and there was not bad feelings between the two.

I know that all these points are just suggestion but there will be no concrete answer in the films but I am pretty confident in saying that no they were not both there at the same time.

Comment: very good answer. we also do have to assume that in the interim when Ra's al ghul becomes injured and Bruce becomes batman Ra's might have spoken to her daughter about going to Gotham which would reveal Bane knowing Batman's identity.

Comment: Thanks, although I would disagree with what you said. Talia said she did not forgive her father until Bruce killed him which would suggest that she would not have been talking to him (although it is possible). I think we are just supposed to assume that Bane figured out that Bruce Wane was Batman as this is what happens in the comics

Comment: @hmmmm Are you saying that Bane doesn't look significantly older than Talia?

Comment: @PriestVallon No I was saying that Bane does not look significantly older when talia/raz al ghul return to the prison than he did when Talia left, hence my justification that it is only maybe 5 years

Answer (score 1):

The only two possibilities are that:

1) Bane trained a short time with the LoS and was excommunicated shortly before Bruce arrived, or...

2) Bruce and Bane were trained at the same time, at least for an extent, and intentionally kept separate.

Comment: Why is it not also possible that Bane was trained after Bruce Wayne had completed his training?